# What is the significance of configure TTL value while creating A record and AAAA Record in External DNS

Tags: network, dns

Is Time to live (TTL) value has any impact on DNS querry . Because in our external DNS we generally set TTL value to 1 hours and some times 5 minutes while creating A records and AAAA records in external DNS .

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

The TTL value in a DNS record specifies the maximum time in seconds that this record remains valid, ie. that it may be cached.

It's good practice to use a fairly large value (e.g. 86,400 for 24h) for records that don't frequently change but when they do, decrease the TTL to a few minutes (24h in advance) to help the update propagate.